# Exception handler for REST controller in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, aop

I want to handle exceptions so the URL information is automatically shown to the client. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
<bean id="outboundExceptionAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <!-- what property to set here? -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two choices:

[Spring Reference 15.9.1 HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#d0e29676)

> Spring HandlerExceptionResolvers ease the pain of unexpected
>   exceptions that occur while your request is handled by a controller
>   that matched the request. HandlerExceptionResolvers somewhat resemble
>   the exception mappings you can define in the web application
>   descriptor web.xml. However, they provide a more flexible way to
>   handle exceptions. They provide information about which handler was
>   executing when the exception was thrown. Furthermore, a programmatic
>   way of handling exceptions gives you more options for responding
>   appropriately before the request is forwarded to another URL (the same
>   end result as when you use the servlet specific exception mappings).

The [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) has one method, containing everything you need:

```
HandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response,
              Object handler, Exception ex)
```

Or if you need different handlers for different controllers: [Spring Reference Chapter 15.9.2 @ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
public String handleIOException(IOException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
   return "every thing you asked for: " + request;
}
```

*Short question short answer*

Comment: The handler topic in the reference is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the following trick:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public ModelAndView handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
         ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:errorMessage?error="+exception.getMessage());
         return mv;
              } 

  @RequestMapping(value="/errorMessage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @Responsebody
  public String handleMyExceptionOnRedirect(@RequestParamter("error") String error) {
     return error;
          }
```

Works flawless.